# How to copy delimited file from s3 to redshift with line breaks written as '\n'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to copy a '|' delimited file with multiple entries to redshift from s3. I have added line breaks as '\n' to my file which is not being read by redshift as line breaks and throws 'Extra column(s) found'.

The data is being processed by lambda which adds \n and encodes in base64.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Tried COPY?

Comment: Please Edit your question to show us the command you are using the load the data, a sample of your data and the exact error message that it returns. This way, we can attempt to reproduce your problem. Also, is Redshift complaining about _every_ row, or just some rows? Did you look in `stl_load_errors`?